# Outlook 2010 Photos Stopped Showing Up

Tags: exchange, outlook, exchange-2010

We have all of our employee photos loaded into Active Directory in the thumbnailPhoto attribute.  When we first setup Exchange 2010 the photos were all showing up in Outlook 2010 correctly and it worked great.

Recently the photos have stopped showing up for everyone in Outlook 2010.  We've verified through several means that they photos are still in Active Directory (mainly through ADSI edit).  We've checked and double checked our attributes, tried setting them back to the defaults, tried removing thumbnailPhoto as an Indicator and added it back in as a Value in an attempt to make the photos all download as part of the GAL, but this didn't work either.

What else can I try to get my photos to show up again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2010/06/01/455005.aspx:

> ... the mAPIID [on the thumbnailPhoto] attribute should have the
>   value 35998. This happens when domain
>   controllers are running Windows 2008
>   or later, or if your Active Directory
>   schema has been updated to Windows
>   2008.

We haven't updated our schema to 2008 so apparently the photos aren't supported in our environment yet.  The weird part is that they worked to begin with.  Apparently some patch or Service Pack we installed fixed this "bug" so that this requirement is now being enforced.